# Mocking and testing classes with multiple constructor parameters

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, mocking, moq

My service layer classes are setup for constructor injection. When mocking and testing these classes, how can I avoid having to pass in `null` for parameters I won't be using in my test?

Sample code I'm trying to avoid:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeServicesTests
{
    SomeServices _someServices;

    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _someServices= new SomeServices (null, 
                                        new StubRepositoryOne(), 
                                        null, 
                                        null, 
                                        new StubRepositoryTwo(), 
                                        null, 
                                        null, 
                                        null,
                                        null);

    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_Something()
    {
        string input = "yes";
        string exptectedOutput = "no";

        string output = _someServices.SomeFunction(input); // uses StubRepositoryOne and StubRepositoryTwo
        Assert.AreEqual(exptectedOutput, output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally validate injected parameters vs. null. I'd normally just pass in

```
new Mock<T>().Object
```

for these.

Comment: But how do I pass in `StubRepositoryOne` and `StubRepositoryTwo` if they're both private in `SomeServices`?

Comment: @Omar - I'd use public interfaces for dependencies instead of private classes. Are the Stub... classes actually stubs? If so and you're using Moq (as your tags imply) then let Moq create stubs of your interface on the fly (as I show above - replace T with your interface).

Comment: So there's no way to have Moq create my service class, stubbing all the parameters except the ones I specify `StubRepositoryOne/StubRepositoryTwo`?

Comment: @Omar - You don't want Moq to create your class under test. You want an actual instance to test, not a mock/fake/stub. Moq creates fake **dependencies**. It's an isolation/mocking framework, not an IoC container. I'd recommend reading more on testing, such as the book [The Art Of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Adding my answer after it's already been accepted, but...

The very fact that only some of the dependencies need to be passed in for the test suggests a possible design problem.  A good litmus test is that all fields in a type should be used in every method -- very hard to do this all the time -- but if you can't it means that the class can probably be broken into smaller classes with finer responsibilities.  When you break them down, each class would take only the dependencies they immediately need.

On the other hand if what you're doing here is a hand-rolled service locator and you're only testing a subset of functionality, you might want to consider creating test only constructors.  Such as:

```
internal SomeServices(IServiceOne one, IServiceTwo two)
{
}
```

Or expose the services with getters/setters and assign accordingly.  Again, the internal keyword here can be used to keep your design intent clean:

```
public IServiceOne One
{
   get { return _one; }
   internal set { _one = value; }
}
```

Of course, you'd want to add the InternalsVisibleTo attribute to your code to allow your tests to access these internal methods.

Comment: You're correct, I do smell a design problem with the service classes.

Answer (score 2):

Stub all missing arguments, and always check for null args inside the SomeService. Checking inputs for null every time you use it is cumbersome. So, better always check for null in the constructor, and throw a ArgumentNullException.

You mention that some inputs arguments are private. They have to be extracted, for your injection pattern to work.